# In App purchase server notification for consumable, there's a way?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to set an environment that sends a notification to my server when a consumable in-app is purchased by an user..

The simplest solution is to take the result `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` in

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

and make an un update in my server by my own. Something like "this in-app" is just buyed from the user xyz@mysite.com.

But this mechanism requires two different moment:

1- the purchase process (ended in the updatedTransactions method)
2- a web call to a webservice (in my server) that update the status to "succes payment"

But what happen if for example, there's a connection problem beetween point 1 and 2 ?

My consumable in-app risks to be payed without set the "succes payment" with this configuration, so my question is:

There's a way to give a notification (maybe with the receipit inside) from the Apple server to my server just after the payment?

Comment: Apple server notifications are only for subscriptions. What you should do is not finish the transaction until it has been recorded on your servers successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so if i don't call [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]; until  success has been recorded on my server the money transfer will not happen? Because i always thinked that in the moment of " case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:" ( in paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions method, where i have to call finistransaction )  the in-app value was already charged in the credit card of the user.

Comment: The money transfer will happen, but you'll be able to know if the purchase was recorded properly. It won't be removed from the queue until you finish the transaction.